# Custom WordPress permalink structure

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Is it possible to have the following structure, and if so, how:

- www.example.com/**something** (A custom archive page with posts from a certain post category ['poca'] and a certain custom post type ['cuty'])
- www.example.com/**something**/beautiful (A post of category ['poca'])
- www.example.com/**something**/ugly (A post of my custom post type ['cuty'])

I can achieve to get my custom archive page to work. Moreover everything works so that 'poca' and 'cuty' takes the same template. But coming from **something** to one of these posts, it takes the normal permalink (category-name or custom-post-type) instead of **something**

Is there a way to achieve that it takes my custom archive page into the url instead?

By the way: I am able to achieve the result by using a custom shortcode for my custom post type and then creating a new post with that shortcode in the wanted category, but this brings a consistency problem, as there's always the need to create two posts for the one thing I'd like to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found a solution. Seems not the best way but it's ok for me to do it this way...

Through using the plugin "Custom Permalinks" I can add the permalink I want, so I only need to add **something** for all my new posts in that category and all new posts of my custom post type. But I am still searching for a solution which does that part automatically if somebody knows...